# Convert <span> tag as a Date picker

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my GUI view in html [image] and my html code is

```html
 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5" style="    padding: 35px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 16px;">From</span>
                    <p style="padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 15px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="font-size:30px">
                            <input type="date" dataformatas=""/>
                            <span class="muve-span-date"><?php echo date('Y-m-01'); ?></span>
                        </i>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 40px;" class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="vl"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5" style="padding: 35px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 16px;">To</span>
                    <p style="padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 15px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="font-size:30px">
                            <span class="muve-span-date"><?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?></span>
                        </i>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

. how can i convert this span tag as a date picker.

Thanks,
Buddhika.

Comment: @BuddhikaLakshan Can you elaborate your question.

Comment: @buddhika-lakshan can you also mark answers as correct or comment on why they are not good enough?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to implement a datepicker instead of a span.

Easiest way would be to just use [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) and let the browser handle this for you. Downside of this is that you can't really style this input.

Second option is to use a javascript library that takes care of rendering the datepicker, two popular choices are:

- [Bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

This are only 2 options, if you search for `javascript datepicker` you will find a lot more, so feel free to chose a different one if you don't like the 2 mentioned above.